# show that $ \ a_n \leq x \leq a_n+\frac{1}{b^n} \ $ for any base $b \neq 10 $ holds for any real number in $[0,1]$.

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-number-theory

Every infinite sequence $ \ 0. a_1a_2a_3 \cdots \cdots $ represents a real number  $ \ x \in [0,1] $ and $ \ \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} \frac{a_i}{10^i} \leq x \leq  \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} \frac{a_i}{10^i} +\frac{1}{10^n} $ in decimal system for all $ n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Prove the similar inequality $ \ \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} \frac{a_i}{b^i} \leq x \leq \sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_i}{b^i}+\frac{1}{b^n} \ $ for any base $b \neq 10 $.

**Answer:**

For any base $ \ b $ other than $ 10$ , a real number $ \ x \in [0,1] $ can be expressed as

$ x= \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n b^{-n} =a_0+\frac{a_1}{b}+\frac{a_2}{b^2}+\cdots +\frac{a_n}{b^n}+\cdots \cdots , \ \text{where $a_0 < 1$}. $

Thus, $ \ x \in [0,1] $.

But how to show that
$ \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} \frac{a_i}{b^i} \leq x \leq \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} \frac{a_i}{b^i} +\frac{1}{b^n} $ holds good?

Help me showing this

Comment: I think you're using "$a_n$" to stand for two different things -- as written your claim doesn't have a chance of being true.

Comment: @HenningMakholm, yes you are true. I have made correction of my question. Thanks

Comment: Question, everywhere you mention $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} a_n$ wasn't you supposed to write $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} \frac{a_n}{10^n}$? And similarly $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} \frac{a_n}{b^n}$?

Comment: @rtybase, I mention that case for decimal number system. Please see the question again

Comment: @yourmath your question is wrongly written the way it is, regardless of how many times I read it ... it must be $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} \frac{a_i}{10^i}$ in case of decimal system and $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} \frac{a_i}{b^i}$ in case of base-$b$. Otherwise, $x=0.111111... \Rightarrow 1+1+1+1 + ... > x$

Comment: @rtybase, I already got the proof. Thanks for giving time

Comment: @yourmath and I have a proof as well, but I can't answer a wrongly written question ... the fact that you have the proof doesn't mean you don't have to fix/clarify your question. It's not polite.

Comment: @rtybase, where the question is wrong? In the first two line I mentioned the result holds in decimal system. This is just for information.  Next, In the 3rd line I asked how to prove the similar inequality for base $b \neq 10$. This one we have to prove. That is all. Where the question goes wrong?

Comment: See my very 1st question, which you seem to deliberately ignore. Given $ \ 0. a_1a_2a_3 \cdots$, this formulation is wrong $ \ \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}a_i \leq x \leq  \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} a_i +\frac{1}{10^n}$, **it must be** $ \ \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\frac{a_i}{10^i} \leq x \leq  \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} \frac{a_i}{10^i} +\frac{1}{10^n}$!

Comment: @rtybase, oh sorry. I got it now. Thanks

Comment: Let me fix it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the difference 
$$0\leq x - \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} \frac{a_i}{b^i} = \sum\limits_{i=n+1}^{\infty} \frac{a_i}{b^i} \leq ...$$
and because $0\leq a_i \leq b-1$ and assuming an integer base $b>1$, we have
$$ ... \leq \sum\limits_{i=n+1}^{\infty} \frac{b-1}{b^i}=
\frac{b-1}{b^{n+1}} \left(\color{red}{\sum\limits_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{b^{i}}}\right)=
\frac{b-1}{b^{n+1}} \left(\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{b}}\right)=\frac{1}{b^n}$$
the sum in red is an infinite geometric progression with ratio $\left|\frac{1}{b}\right|<1$.